# how to create single alert for multiple resource in azure

Tags: azure, cloud

**I wanted to create alert for multiple Virtual Machines and App services. For VM it is related to cpu usage and for App service based on http 500 alert. How to do it**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is an existing issue raised in Github [`Multiple conditions in SIngle Alert rule`](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/12984)

> Currently, you can create alerts for specific resource
>   based-operations on activity log at a subscription level, resource
>   group level and a specific resource level. The operation selected in
>   an alert can be for a single resource only like
>   Microsoft.Compute/virtualMachines/start/action. And you'll need to
>   create multiple alerts if they span across multiple resources; as in
>   your question.

Here is the [uservoice](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/602299-azure-alert-management/suggestions/35060563-support-multi-action-alert-rule-specification-in-s).

Answer (score 0):

Currently it is possible to create [rule for multiple VMs](https://azure.microsoft.com/nl-nl/blog/monitor-at-scale-in-azure-monitor-with-multi-resource-metric-alerts/)

> With this new feature, you will be able to set up a single metric alert rule that monitors:
>
> - A list of virtual machines in one Azure region
> - All virtual machines in one or more resource groups in one Azure region
> - All virtual machines in a subscription in one Azure region

Answer (score 0):

There is a limited number of resource types that can have metric Alerts on multiple resources https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/alerts/alerts-metric-overview#monitoring-at-scale-using-metric-alerts-in-azure-monitor.

Notes:

- I have been able to get this working with powershell, but not via the portal.
- Activity log Alerts and Log Analytics Alerts are different and can be used on Multiple resources.
- Some resources can be grouped with via individual selection (in the portal*) E.g. Sql db. This is where you can select db1,db2,db6 but note the others.

*I have yet to try this with powershell.